# Python: how to access eval's globals() inside eval

Tags: python, scope, eval

The title seems stupid but i don't know how to express it precisely, sorry.

I have a program that need to eval some user code (through RestrictedPython for security) and I want to put a function into the eval's globals so that it can print out some debug information to me when eval, for example (simplify):

```
class UserException(Exception):
    pass


def err(msg):
    # ? how to get the globals variable in eval ?
    A = globals().get('A', 'A not found')
    return UserException("%s and A's value is %r" % (msg, A))

g = {
    'err': err,
    'A': None,
    '__builtins__': {},
}

print eval('A or err("A not true")', g)
```

this will give the resut:

```
A not true and A's value is 'A not found'
```

Using 'globals()' here insde 'err' is of course wrong. But how can i get the value in 'g' inside 'err'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any reference to `globals()` from inside a function will always give you the globals that were in scope when the function was defined. What you are seeing here is no different than when you import a function from one module into another: the imported function still refers to the globals of the module where it was defined.

The simplest way to get the function to use `g` as its `globals()` would be to exec the definition using `g` as the globals. If you do change the globals for the function then don't foget you also need to include any other globals that the function uses; in this case `UserException`.

Alternatively you could make `err()` inspect the stack frame of its caller and use the caller's globals. That's messy, but if it's for debug information may be acceptable to you.

```
>>> def err(msg):
    # ? how to get the globals variable in eval ?
    A = sys._getframe(1).f_globals.get('A', 'A not found')
    return UserException("%s and A's value is %r" % (msg, A))

>>> import sys
>>> g = {
    'err': err,
    'A': None,
    '__builtins__': {},
}
>>> print eval('A or err("A not true")', g, g)
A not true and A's value is None
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm looking for. I use the inspect module to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it `g` as a default argument:

```
def err(msg, g=g):
    A = g['A']
    return UserException("%s and A's value is %r" % (msg, A))
```

will give the result: `A not true and A's value is None`.